# My PC hangs during Windows installation

Tags: windows-7, boot, freeze, windows-installation

My ASUS ROG G30AB desktop has been used for one and a half years, mostly running World Of Tanks and Armored Warfare.  Recently, it started hanging frequently while playing a game, causing Windows 8.1 to crash irrecoverably and corrupts the OS (freeze at automatic repair).

I have tried to format the HDD and install Windows 7.  After it was successfully installed, I managed to  update all of the drivers.  I ran the World Of Tanks game again for three hours, with GPU and CPU temperature monitored. The temperature was between 50 and 60 degrees Celsius, but the PC hung again, and yes, Windows crashed irrecoverably.

At this moment, my PC can still run MiniXP from HirenBootCD, and still boot up Ubuntu.  A HDD test shows no bad sector.

I tried to install Windows 7 again, but after it copied all files to my PC, the  PC hung on the next startup to install the files.  I repeated the process of formatting the HDD and reinstalling Windows 7 few times, but it always hangs at the start of installing the OS.

Comment: Too many questions at once, I think. It may be closed as too broad. Can you simplify or perhaps split into more than one question?

Comment: Most likely is the problem around your HDD, Check your HDD with diagnostic software's. Also check your PowerSupply to working good and stable.

Comment: You provide lots of good detail, but there's a bit that is unclear.  The question summary is "What might happen if PC hang during windows installation?"  Are you having questions about a freeze that occurs during the actual action of installing Windows?  If so, your detailed description doesn't reinforce that's your actual major question.  Is your main question just trying to figure out different possible causes?  Unfortunately, all your details have left us with a bit less clarity, not more.  For this question, please provide a summarizing sentence or two focused on 1 single concise question.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. In summary, I have replaced with new power supply, tested HDD (formatting at low level and checking for bad sectors) and installed Ubuntu successfully but I cannot install Windows 7 on my PC. Any action do I need to do to "give you guys more clue" or "solve this issue"?

By the way, I am going to check to make sure legacy boot up option in bios is enable.

Comment: Do an extended memtest (several hours)

Comment: Also, you have not "low level formatted" the hard drive. You have formatted the hard drive. You can't low-level *anything* a modern hard drive.